# Get webview document title when HTML is loaded

Tags: c++, qt, webview

I have the following Qt webview:

```
QWebView *view = new QWebView();
view->load(QUrl("http://example.com"));
```

I want to get the title of document when load is finished, and use it to set the main window title.

From what I suppose `view->loadFinished()` returns `true` if page was loaded or not.

For setting the window title I use `webView->setWindowTitle(newTitle)`. So, I need that `newTitle` variable that I want to be the document title.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QWebView::loadFinished` is a signal. You can subscribe to it to know when the page is loaded:

```
connect(view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), this, SLOT(onLoaded()));
```

To access HTML title you can use `QWebView::title` property.

```
void onLoaded()
{
    window->setWindowTitle(view->title());
}
```

Rather then using `loadFinished` it may be more appropriate to use signal `titleChanged(const QString& title)` to apply a new title to the window:

```
connect(view, SIGNAL(titleChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(setWindowTitle(QString)));
```

EDIT:
Example:

```
QWebView* webView = new QWebView();
connect(webView, SIGNAL(titleChanged(QString)), webView, SLOT(setWindowTitle(QString)));
webView->load(QUrl("http://yahoo.com"));
webView->show();
```

Comment: In both `connect` lines a parenthese (`)` at the end) is missing I guess. However I get the following error: `/main.cpp:...: error: 'connect' was not declared in this scope`. Do I have to include any libraries?

Comment: From where do you call `connect`? It is a static method of `QObject`. You can also use `QObject::connect` but the third argument should be a `QWidget` descendant.

Comment: From the main file (`main.cpp`). Using `QObject::connect(view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), view, SLOT(onLoaded()));`, I get the following output: `QObject::connect: No such slot QWebView::onLoaded()`. So, how to use `connect` or `QObject::connect` correctly?

Comment: If you show `QWebView` as as window, you can use the second `connect` replacing `this` with `view`: `connect(view, SIGNAL(titleChanged(QString)), view, SLOT(setWindowTitle(QString)));`. Otherwise change `this` to `webView` independently of whatever it it. Here is a [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) about signals and slots.

Comment: Yes, the window is the webview actually. How can take the real document title (`<title>foo</title>`) from webview?

Comment: Added a working example. "Real title" is in `titleChanged` signal. You can get it via webView->title() also.